# Time complexity of an algoithm with multiple loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Let us assume we have an algorithm with the following structure:

1. A for-loop with O(n) complexity.
2. Another for-loop with O(n) complexity.

   - Inside this loop is a search algorithm with O(log n) complexity executed in every iteration of the for-loop.

Now, what time complexity does this algorithm have? Is it O(n^2), O(n), O(n log n) or something else?

Comment: What do *you* think it is, and why?

Comment: @ScottHunter I am not sure, but I would guess O(n log n) since maybe the complexities multiply, because for every n step we need to do a log n task.

Comment: are the 2 `O(n)` loops nested ?

Comment: @TestoTesta You have answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be O(n + nlogn) which is **`O(n logn)`**

If you want to learn about big-O notation I recommend this book: `Introduction to algorithms`

**Link:** https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms-third-edition